# Xubuntu 18.04 problem with keyboard key

Tags: keyboard, xubuntu, keyboard-layout, xfce

I have two keys that don't work. I tried use the keyboard and language GUI to reconfigure the keys.

Strangely, I can press `>`, but the greater sign `<` does not work, and the other key is the `1`, but I can do the `!` mark.

Any idea to how to fix this problem?

I think that the keys work because the `Ctrl` + Key combinations work.

I am running Xubuntu 18.04 with Xfce, on a HP Pavellion 15 laptop.